# MapDispatchToProps doesn't work on returning an object

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

If I make my own **mapDispatchToProps** function, it doesn't work. If I give a plain object for connect then it does work, but I need the dispatch functionality.. for eg loading of translations per page, Am I doing something wrong here?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => { 

    const { isFetching, lastUpdated, items, errors } = state.transactions; // fetch from redux state ;)

    return {
        translate: getTranslate(state.locale),
        isFetching,
        lastUpdated,
        items,
        errors
    }
} 
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {

    return { 
        fetchTransactionsIfNeeded, 
        invalidateList 
     }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Transactions);
```

The code below works

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => { 

    const { isFetching, lastUpdated, items, errors } = state.transactions; // fetch from redux state ;)

    return {
        translate: getTranslate(state.locale),
        isFetching,
        lastUpdated,
        items,
        errors
    }
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { 
       fetchTransactionsIfNeeded, 
       invalidateList 
})(Transactions);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: no I don't get any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the redux documentation

> ***[mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or Function):*** If an object is passed, each function inside it is
>   assumed to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function
>   names, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so
>   they may be invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s
>   props.
>
> If a function is passed, it will be given dispatch as the first
>   parameter. It’s up to you to return an object that somehow uses
>   dispatch to bind action creators in your own way. (Tip: you may use
>   the bindActionCreators() helper from Redux.)

In first case when you implement mapDispatchToProps, you are returning a plain object, but you need to use dispatch in it, since its not assumed as an action creator by itself by redux.

You would implement it like

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {

    return { 
        fetchTransactionsIfNeeded: (...args) => {
               dispatch(fetchTransactionsIfNeeded(...args))
         }, 
        invalidateList: (...args) => {
               dispatch(invalidateList(...args))
         },
     }
}
```

or else don't create it as a function but simply an object

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { 
       fetchTransactionsIfNeeded, 
       invalidateList 
}
```

Comment: Hell yea! You just helped me solve a bug at work that I've been banging my head against